# Extract the value of a particular field from different types of method arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I am writing an interceptor for the service methods in my spring boot application like below:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

  public MyAspect() {
   
  }

  @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
  public void applicationServicePointcut() {
  }

  @Before(value = ("applicationServicePointcut()"))
  public void process(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {
   ...
    
  }
}
```

One such service is as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AService {
   
  public ADTO create(ADTO aDTO) {
    ...
  }

  public ADTO update(ADTO aDTO) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Another service can be as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BService {
   
  public BDTO create(BDTO bDTO) {
    ...
  }

  public BDTO update(BDTO bDTO) {
    ...
  }
  
  public void doSomething(String a, int b) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here my goal is to extract the value of a particular field from the associated method arguments. In order to do this, I can write a single function in aspect, where I can have multiple if-else blocks as follows:

```
 String extractMyField(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
  
     //extract the arguments of the associated method from joinpoint
     //depending on the type of arguments, extract the value of myfield as follows

    if(arg instance of ADTO) {
       ...
     } else if (arg instance of BDTO) {
       ...
     }
     ...
    }
```

It can be seen in the above code snippet, there can be the following cases:

1. the method argument can be an object as well as primitive types as well.
2. there can be zero or more method arguments.

Also, I cannot change the DTO objects as well.

I am wondering if there can be a better approach to do this. Basically, I am looking for a way to make it easily extensible.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

**EDIT**

As of now, in order to process the method arguments, first I have been collecting the method arguments as follows:

```
      Map<String, Object> getMethodArguments(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    
        Map<String, Object> argumentNameValueMap = new HashMap<>();
    
        if (methodSignature.getParameterNames() == null) {
          return argumentNameValueMap;
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < methodSignature.getParameterNames().length; i++) {
          String argumentName = methodSignature.getParameterNames()[i];
          Object argumentValue = joinPoint.getArgs()[i];
          Class argumentType = joinPoint.getArgs()[i].getClass();
          //check if i th parameter is json serializable
          if (Objects.isNull(methodSignature.getParameterTypes()) ||
              isJsonSerializable(methodSignature.getParameterTypes()[i])) {
            argumentNameValueMap.put(argumentName, mapper.convertValue(argumentValue, Map.class));
          }
        }
        return argumentNameValueMap;
       }

        private boolean isJsonSerializable(Class parameterType) {
    return
        !Objects.isNull(parameterType) &&
            !parameterType.getName().endsWith("HttpServletRequest") &&
            !parameterType.getName().endsWith("HttpServletResponse") &&
            !parameterType.getName().endsWith("MultipartFile");
  }
```

Actually, the catch here is that the field I am looking for is named differently across DTOs. For example, in ADTO the field is named as `id` whereas, in BDTO, it's named as `aId`.

Comment: A question: what is 'value of myfield' is it "guaranteed" to have myfield with a value in all the DTOs? What if the Aspect intercepts the method that doesn't have any parameter with myfield?

Comment: @MarkBramnik Yeah this is also a valid case. It may happen, some method does not have this parameter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then let me suggest the following:

I assume, you can't change the DTO objects
I assume, sometimes your methods won't even have DTO parameters, but you have a logic to "find" them if they exist

If you know what are the types of the intercepted DTOs are, you can create the interface:

```
interface DTOHandler {
   Class<?> getDTOClass();
   Object getMyField(Object dtoObject); 
}
```

Implement this interface for each DTO

For example, if you plan to intercept 2 different types of DTOs:

```
class ADTO {
  Integer myField;
}
class BDTO {
  String myField;
}
```

Then implement:

```
class DTOAHandler implements DTOHandler {
   Class<?> getDtoClass() {return ADTO.class;}
   Object getMyField(Object obj) {return ((ADTO)obj).getMyField();}
}

// and do a similar implementation same for DTOB
```

Now define all these handlers as spring beans and inject a list of them into the aspect. Spring boot will inject them all as a list, the order doesn't matter

In the constructor of the aspect create a map of Class<?> -> DTOHandler.
Iterate throw the list and create a key of the map as a call of 'getDTOClass' and the value as a handler itself:

```
public class MyAspect {

   private Map<Class<?>, DTOHandler> handlersRegistry;

   public MyAspect(List<DTOHandler> allHandlers) {
      handlersRegistry = new HashMap<>();
      for(DTOHandler h : allHandlers) {
        handlersRegistry.put(h.getDTOClass(), h);
      }
   }
}
```

With this setup the `extractMyField` will look as follows:

```
public void extractMyField(JoinPoint jp) {
    
     Object myDTO = findDTOParameter(jp);
     
     DTOHandler handler = this.handlersRegistry.get(myDTO.getClass());
     if(handler != null) {
       // there is an actual handler for this type of DTOs
        Object myField = handler.getMyField(myDTO);
     }
     else {
       // the aspect can't handle the DTO of the specified type
     }
}
```

**Update** (based on Op's comment):

In order to actually find a parameter that has a 'myfield' value, you've used a pretty complicated logic (in the EDIT section of the question).

Instead you can create an annotation (runtime retention) that can be applied to the parameters.

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface @DTO {
}
```

Then you can annotate with this annotation the parameters in the service to "help" your aspect to understand which of the parameters are actually DTOs:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AService {
   
  public ADTO create(@DTO ADTO aDTO) {
    ...
  }

  public ADTO update(@DTO ADTO aDTO) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, the resolution logic in the aspect will become something like:

```
// pseudocode
foreach p in 'parameters' {
  if(isAnnotatedWith(p, DTO.class))  {
     // it matches
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have one small doubt. As of now, I have been collecting the method arguments as mentioned in the EDIT section of the OP. So I think, I can use the class of the arguments in order to use the approach as you mentioned.

Comment: As long as this class is the same as the class of the Handler, why not? I guess you can use that approach. At least you can try whether it works for you :) For the Resolution, instead of the logic you've posted in 'EDIT ' Consider adding an annotation on parameter and check it in the aspect (of course if you can change the service's code).

Comment: Sure. If possible, could you please briefly explain the approach using annotation?  Actually, I don't have any idea about working with such custom annotation.

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

How about making your ADTO/BDTO implementing a custom interface

```
interface AspectDataProvider {
  String aspectSpecificData()
}
```

Then in your argument processor, you can do easily

```
if (arg instanceof AspectDataProvider) {
  return ((AspectDataProvider) arg).aspectSpecificData();
}
```

Or you can dig deeper and drop in a visitor pattern for your implementation

```
  interface AspectImplementor {
     void executeAspect(String value);
  }

  interface AspectAware {
     void accept(AspectImplementor aspect);
  }
```

Then in your BDTO ADTO add a custom implementation of `AspectAware`

```
  void accept(AspectImplementor aspect) {
    String property = // object-specific property extraction
    aspect.executeAspect(property);
  }
```

And in your aspect, you can write similar

```
  if (arg instanceof AspectAware ) {
    ((AspectAware ) arg).accept(aspectExecutorInstance);
  }
```

But I would not recommend starting with the design pattern from the very beginning - it should always be the next improvement, once you are sure you have a visitor pattern.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, I am sorry, I did not mention in the OP that, I cannot change the DTOs as well as the arguments can be of primitive type as well.